# Removing the password from a PDF file

Tags: pdf, passwords

I have a couple of ebooks as PDFs with passwords, however my ebook reader (sony prs600) doesn't seem to support PDFs with passwords.  What is the easiest of removing the password from a PDF (I know the password, which presumably helps a lot).  It's a bit annoying buying a book and then only being able to read it in front of a computer.

Comment: What did you finally use to remove the password? I was in similar situation except I forgot the permission password I used to protect my PDF's. Tried some of the solutions mentioned here but I couldn't remove the password. Somehow I managed to remove the password and the restrictions only from FEW PDF's by following the tips mentioned in this guide: http://www.techbii.com/remove-pdf-password-restriction/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With **[A-PDF Restrictions Remover](http://download.cnet.com/A-PDF-Restrictions-Remover/3000-10743_4-10598299.html?tag=mncol)**, you can remove the password and other restrictions in a few seconds.

*A-PDF Restrictions Remover is shareware ($10), try before you buy.*

Comment: The trial version of this worked perfectly - I think I'll be registering ;-)

Comment: @Alister - if you work a lot with protected PDFs, it's well worth it :)

Comment: -1 Why pay, when there are free solutions available?

Answer (score 18):

https://mupdf.com/downloads/index.html

I tried the Win32 `pdfclean` binary for MuPDF 0.5: https://web.archive.org/web/20191119070425/https://mupdf.com/downloads/archive/mupdf-0.5-win32.zip

I was able to remove the password without having to know the source password.

```
pdfclean clean protected.pdf pdfwithnopassword.pdf
```

---

*MuPDF, available for at least Windows and macOS (via Homebrew) has a free command line tool called [`mutool`](http://mupdf.com/news).
I personally used it to remove the password on my American Express statement and merge all my separate PDF statements into one giant PDF.
The command line is:
mutool clean protected.pdf pdfnopassword.pdf*

Comment: I found this the easiest. You don't need to install anything. No trial version. No nagging to buy something. It just works.

Comment: In 2017 this is an excellent free option. `mupdf` is available for OSX users via Homebrew as well.

Comment: This didn't work for me on the latest (1.14.0) version of mutool, the output file was still password protected. I then tried with an earlier version (1.3) and it stripped the password out, but I had to supply the password for the original. So ended up with `mutool.exe clean -p "myPassword" protected.pdf` I found 1.3 [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mupdf/downloads)

Comment: As of version 1.15.0 (which can be downloaded from [here](https://www.mupdf.com/downloads/index.html)), password protection can be removed (assuming the password is available) with: `mutool clean -p "myPassword" -D protected.pdf pdfnopassword.pdf`. The `-D` flag [is not currently documented](https://www.mupdf.com/docs/manual-mutool-clean.html), but was added in commit [60b13ad](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=mupdf.git;a=commit;h=60b13ad3f7a1b597152d079b336fbbed75942998). @Matt

Comment: My comment wasn't to criticize your answer (I didn't down-vote it), but to bring new information, and was somewhat in response to Matt's comment.

Comment: @TamirEvan@Matt Thanks, I didn't take it as a criticism. Its my fault for not including the version number. MUPDF 0.5 and tried pdfclean and it removed password without entering the password. I tried https://mupdf.com/downloads/archive/mupdf-0.5-win32.zip

Comment: [`mutool`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/mutool.1.html) is also available on windows via WSL Ubuntu.  Install with `sudo apt install mupdf-tools`

Comment: The MuPDF 0.5 file linked in the answer is flagged as a virus: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/8d50d640a492eae8990aa7504090dafd328f1b64f0d20cbc389e8e8a6d8fef07

Comment: its a false positive. many av will flag bypass tools as virus even if they are not. up to you if you want to use or not. do what makes you comfortable.

Answer (score 13):

You can try [Easy Pdf Password Remover Free](http://easy-pdf-password-remover-free.software.informer.com/). Other alternatives are:

- [PDF Password Remover](http://techblissonline.com/pdf-password-remover-free/) (freeware)
- [PDF Unlocker](http://freeware-pdf-unlocker.en.softonic.com/) (freeware)

If none of the above worked for you, have a look at this page: [7 easy ways to unlock a PDF file.](http://all-things-tek.blogspot.com/2009/10/7-easy-ways-to-unlock-pdf-file.html)

NOTE: If you have Adobe Acrobat (not the free Acrobat Reader), you can remove the passwords from `File > Document Security > Security Options` by selecting `No Security`.

Comment: The Easy Pdf Password Remover Free only allows for passwords of 3 characters, and you can't specify a password.  I couldn't get PDF Password Remover or Unlocker to work - they are both the same tool based on ghostscript or something.

Comment: I found that http://www.pdfunlock.com/ (from the 7 easy ways to unlock a PDF file) works pretty good, however it was sloooooooow.

Comment: PDF Unlocker worked like a charm!

Comment: After a lot of searching, this one worked me. http://blog.rubypdf.com/pdfcrack/

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [`qpdf`](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/) utility, like so: :

```
qpdf --password=YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE --decrypt your_input.pdf your_output.pdf
```

this is also easy to automate with a shell script to decrypt multiple PDF files.

`qpdf` is available as a package on many/most GNU/Linux distributions. For example, on Debian/Ubuntu-based distributions, you would get it by running:

```
sudo apt install qpdf
```

It is also available for Windows; you can download an installer of the [latest release](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/releases/latest) (from GitHub).

---

*Security note*: If you specify your password on the command-line, your shell may place it, as plain-text, in your command history file.

Answer (score 6):

If you have access to a Mac (and Preview.app), you can try 
"File", "Print", "Save as PDF" or 
"File", "Save as" a PDF document.

This has removed the password on some documents for me. I don't know if these tips are applicable to Adobe Reader.

Comment: For Linux users I suggest they do this using Okular rather than Evince. Okular maintained text information in the process, while Evince failed to maintain that, or page orientation.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Tyilo It does, for any Mac running 10.7 or earlier. It didn't stop working, you just upgraded to a newer software version since this answer was posted. On Mountain Lion, try Preview's *File » Save…*, *File » Duplicate* or *File » Export…*.

Comment: File > Save, exports the file with all pages blank and the other two options, requires me to type the "owner" password although I only know the "user" password.

Comment: @Tyilo Please note that the question states the password (presumably owner password) is known. You don't know it, so this question — and therefore my answer — just don't apply to your situation.

Comment: Fair enough....

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SysTools PDF Unlocker](http://www.systoolsgroup.com/pdf-unlocker.html):

- Microsoft Windows
- non-gratis if you don't want the  SysTools Watermark or need to process batch of PDF files

[image]

It allowed me to remove the security on a password-protected document (for which I knew the password) certified by Adobe EchoSign e-signature service, whereas Adobe Acrobate Pro XI wouldn't let me do it:

[image]

> You cannot change security on this document because the document is signed or certified.

[image]

Trying to print the document also wasn't working:

```
%%[ ProductName: Distiller ]%%
This PostScript file was created from an encrypted PDF file.
Redistilling encrypted PDF is not permitted.
%%[ Flushing: rest of job (to end-of-file) will be ignored ]%%
%%[ Warning: PostScript error. No PDF file produced. ] %%
```