# How to remove a password I know from a PDF, with no degradation, on Linux?

Tags: pdf, passwords, conversion

Someone sent me a password-protected PDF. I know the password, but I want to make the PDF password-less, for convenience.

However - I want to make sure I don't lose any of the information in there. For example, I don't want images to be resampled, or vectorized content rasterized, or text runs/paragraphs broken up, or ancillary/non-critical non-printing data to be lost, I want the document properties meta-data to stay the same (well, perhaps I'm a little flexible about that).

Also, since I'm not a PDF format wiz, I'm not sure I can tell when a PDF has been degraded. So, for example, if I print to PDF from a PDF viewer, I'm not sure if the result is satisfactory - until perhaps someday later I'm trying to import it in a document editor or select some of the text and then find out something has changed.

My question is: Is there a way for me to do this which is qualitatively better than printing to a PDF? Perhaps I can simply remove the password somehow, in-place? Or at least ensure maximum-conservatism in the processing?

Notes:

- I'm using Devuan GNU/Linux 3.0 (which is about the same as Debian Buster).
- There's a near-duplicate question, [Removing the password from a PDF file](https://superuser.com/questions/86266/removing-the-password-from-a-pdf-file?noredirect=1&lq=1) - but the answers there are Windows and Mac utilities.
- I've tried using `pdftk ... input_pw`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Voting to reopen this question after the edit (since it is for Linux and there is no answer that covers this scenario in the duplicate).

Comment: I now have an answer for this question - if it's reopened I'll post it!